# How to export and import google cloud monitoring dashboards between projects using script or API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I have exported the dashboards using `gcloud alpha monitoring dashboards list --format=json`, but using `gcloud dashboard create` using file is not working, basically I want to export the dashboards from one project and import that in other project.

Comment: what error do you see when using `gcloud dashboard create` with file ?

Answer (score 12):

The output of the `list` sub command probably (didn't test this) has too many dashboards for the create command.
Also, you should remove two fields (`name` and `etag`). No need to export as json, yaml will also work and is easier to edit anyway.

I did the following:

- `gcloud monitoring dashboards list` and find the dashboard I was looking for
- Note it's `name` property and get the id from the last part in the `name` property (a large decimal number or guid)
- `gcloud monitoring dashboards describe $DASHBOARD_ID > dashboard-$DASHBOARD_ID.yaml` the dashboard
- Edit the file to remove the `etag` and `name` field (the `name` is usually located at the end of the file)
- `gcloud monitoring dashboards create --config-from-file dashboard-$DASHBOARD_ID.yaml`

Comment: Can confirm. Appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also copy dashboards using the console by opening the JSON editor of the source project dashboard copying the whole source text, creating a new dashboard in the other project, opening the JSON editor and pasting the text from the clipboard.